# A real time Spectrum analyser with pyaudio in python on Raspi

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2

I am trying to get an fft plot on realtime audio using a USB microphone plugged into my raspi. I want to be able to activate an LED when a certain frequency is detected through the fft plot. I have so far tried to get just a live sound wave to be plotted but I am having trouble. I have followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AShHJdSIxkY&lc=z22efhti3uaff52pv04t1aokgg3rlotuia3kw5mpcsnubk0h00410.1510779722591217

I have tried changing the chunk size to a greater value and a lower value but have had no success.For some reason I get the -9981 error but it takes a long time to print the error. No plot is displayed. I have even tried overclocking my Raspberry Pi to see if that would work but it still doesn't work.

I was wondering if anyone else had tried something like this on their Pi and if it was possible or if I had to do it using a different package other than pyaudio.

Here is my python code:

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




CHUNK = 100000
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input = True,
    output = True,
    frames_per_buffer = CHUNK,
    start = True
    )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 2 * CHUNK, 2)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.rand(CHUNK))

ax.set_ylim(0, 255)
ax.set_xlim(0, CHUNK)


while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data_int = np.array(struct.unpack(str(CHUNK*2) + 'B', data), dtype='b')[::2] + 127
    line.set_ydata(data_int)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: What is a `-9981 error` ?

Comment: it says: OSError: [Errno Input Overflowed] -9981, I'm not exactly sure what this means but have seen somewhere that it means that the buffer is getting more data in from the microphone than what is being put out. I still haven't managed to sort this problem out.

Comment: surely there is a line number associated? Since it's unreasonable to expect someone to have the exact set up you have, you should spend more time drilling down to the specifics of the problem. There are multiple possibilities, but right now you haven't provided specific enough information about your error to give a good answer. You describe everything *but* your problem...

Comment: I don't know enough about the error to provide enough information as it is hard to find out what the actual problem is, otherwise I might have already sorted it.

Comment: This issue also posted at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814829/a-real-time-spectrum-analyser-with-pyaudio-in-python-on-raspi)

Comment: Closed as cross-post with SO.